# Click on hyper link is not loading webpage using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, href

Here is how my html looks like on the web page:

```
<form id ="invoice request">
    <div id = "charges">
        <div id = "charges">
            <div id= "billing">
                <a id = "modify" class="modify_link" href = "#"> Modify </a>
```

I am unable to load Web page by clicking on Modify charges link. Selenium test passes without actually loading webpage.

Here are my trails:

```
driver.findElement (By.id  ("modify")).click ();
wait.until (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.id ("modify")).click ();
```

What's wrong in the code?

Comment: I am not sure what Click does on wait.until (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated (By.id ("modify")).click ();

Comment: @Saifur The ExpectedConditions returns a webelement so you can call any webelement.method() directly on a 'wait.until' call.

Comment: You are not executing both lines together. Are you?

Answer (score 0):

You're expected condition doesn't actually do anything there. You're HTML shows that the element is already present when you click, because it's what you clicked. That element will still be on the DOM. You need to find an element (on what I am assuming is an AJAX call) that is presented only after you have clicked the modify button to ensure that the click button you invoked did anything.

Comment: once I Clicked on the modify this is what I got <div id="contentBody">
<div id="controller" class="formbody contentBox uti_charges_corinvitem_charges">

Comment: verify the visibility of the locator with id='contentBody'                        wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.id ("contentBody"))

Comment: Thanks so much @Rishi. Its working fine with wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.id ("contentBody"))